# One who takes leave without notice

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm pretty sure that I know a word for a person who takes leave without informing in advance but I am not able to recollect it.

> Don't count on him to finish the work today. He is a _______.
>
> "We don't encourage people who are _________. Serious actions will be taken against them", said the manager.

An *absentee* is a person who is expected to be there but they're not. But the person might have given a heads up that they will be absent. So that doesn't fit well.

Comment: AWOL? Standing for Absent With Out Leave ...

Comment: But perhaps not suitable for your example.  Unless it were "He is AWOL," and "We don't encourage people to be AWOL."

Comment: Malingerer, shirker, unreliable, hypochondriac, bad at time management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you need is **skiver**.

> a person who is absent from work without permission

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/skiver)

> Tom Colella, an electrician from Perth, Australia, took **skiving off work** to new levels. On at least 140 separate occasions,

[IFL](http://www.iflscience.com/technology/electrician-skived-off-work-using-chip-packets-to-hide-his-gps-location/)

Comment: skiver is more related to laziness, I think OP might want to refer to a person who has habit of leaving without notice or warning instead of just because the person is lazy

Comment: @Neo The Cambridge Dictionary appears to disagree with you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the words *renegade* and deserter are a little strong for the context provided.

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/renegade) says:

> Definition of renegade
>   NOUN
>
> A person who deserts and betrays an organization, country, or set of principles.
>   ‘an agent who later turns out to be a renegade’

Whereas [the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/awol) says:

> AWOL
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Military 
>   usually predicative Absent from where one should be but without intent to desert.
>
> ‘the men have gone AWOL’
>
> Origin
>   1920s: acronym from absent without (official) leave.

This term, though, is an adj. rather than a noun but, depending on the tone/context of what's been written it might be closer to what is being sought.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are referring to is [Renegade](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renegade)

Comment: Can you please tell me why is renegade a good fit?

Comment: Deserter may fit it too, I am not too sure.